# Convert date to desired format in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `RegistruTransport` and columns `DataExpirareAutD` (stored as a `Date`) and `FirmaD` (stored as nvarchar).

I want to change date format; I am using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATE, (SELECT DISTINCT DataExpirareAutD
                   FROM RegistruTransport
                   WHERE FirmaD = @NumeFirma), 103)
```

I am trying to get the date corresponding to the name typed in a textbox and `@NumeFirma` is a parameter. I am working in Visual Studio and till now this query does nothing, date still the same I don't know why.

Comment: mysql or (MS)SQL-Server? Please remove tags for products which are not involved

Comment: what is the format that you want to show.And what is engine that you are using Sql Server or something else.?

Comment: Sqlserver and the format I want is dd/MM/YYYY (103)

Comment: use convert(varchar,<column_name>,103) as Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR,DataExpirareAutD,103)
from RegistruTransport 
WHERE FirmaD=@NumeFirma
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all the date formats I am aware of

```
DECLARE @i INTEGER = 0
WHILE @i < 255
BEGIN
    SELECT @i += 1
    Declare @out Table (zample varchar(max), aline varchar(max))
    BEGIN TRY
    insert into @out(zample, aline)
        SELECT CAST(n AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), GETDATE(), n) xZample, 'CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@YourDateVarHere, ' + CAST(n AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')' AS _________________________tehcode____________________________
        FROM (SELECT @i AS n) x
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
       --do nothing
        exec(';');
    END CATCH
END
select * from @out
```